# FragmentTransaction inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using jfeinstien10's `SlidingMenu`.  The menu that pulls out is a `Fragment`.  When the user clicks on a menu item, it does something like this:

```
FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
SherlockListFragment mFrag = new ItemsFragment();
t.replace(R.id.main_frag, mFrag);
t.commit();
```

However, I have heard that it is not good practice to control a `Fragment` from Another `Fragment`.  In a situation like this, is this an acceptable method?  Or should I be using a Callback Method to the parent `FragmentActivity`.

If a Callback method is the proper way, can I please see an example of how this works?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of performing transaction in fragment, I would suggest you to leave it up to Activity level. To do that, define a public method in your activity and then call it from your fragment. For example:

Suppose your activity is:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ....

    public void replaceFragment(){
        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SherlockListFragment mFrag = new ItemsFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.main_frag, mFrag);
        t.commit();
    }

    ....
}
```

And within your fragment, make the following call:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).replaceFragment();
```