# Android - Button won't switch fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button

I've been trying to get my floating action button to work in my fragment to where it switches and does a slide animation to the next fragment but for some reason when I click on the floating action button, it does nothing. Can someone help me point out why.

Here is my fragment class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ScoutFragment extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton addDataScout;

    public ScoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    } //End of ScoutFragment

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, container, false);

        //Setup Floating Action Button
        FloatingActionButton addDataScout = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        addDataScout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddScoutDataFragment fragment = new AddScoutDataFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } //End of onClick
        }); //End of setOnClickListener

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, container, false);
    } //End of onCreateView
} //End of class
```

Here is the xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.ramfernoscout.ScoutFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="61dp"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_add"
            app:backgroundTint="#F28016"
            app:elevation="5dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:clickable="true">
        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Western University"
            android:id="@+id/testText"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I am also using `NavigationDrawer` for my project

Comment: You can do like this:
[FragmentTransaction inside a Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15504850/5124783)

Comment: You can check my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the container name as `fragment_container` but where is it? What you have to do is to give id to the FrameLayout as `fragment_container`.

add `android:id="@+id/fragment_container"` to the FrameLayout and you are ready to go.

Comment: I changed the id to `android:id="@+id/layoutScout"` then changed the code to `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layoutScout, fragment);` but nothing changed, I click on the button and the other fragment doesn't pop up

Comment: @Samer Alabi change `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, container, false);`
with `return view;` why are you inflating twice??

Comment: That worked somewhat, the other fragment popped up but the other is still there, what do I do to fix that

Comment: @SamerAlabi try calling `container.removeAllViews() ` in the `onCreate` method. As my solution worked can you please accept my answer?

Comment: Like this? (Really new to Android development sorry) `public void onCreate(ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        container.removeAllViews();
    } //End of onCreate`

Comment: sorry I tried to say on your `onCreateView` method. my mistake

Comment: It unfortunately didn't work, it's still overlapping

Comment: can you post an image of how it looks?

Comment: try calling it before inflating view and post me an image of what it looks in the device. I mean snapshot of your application

Comment: Now that's a weird and different issue. I am not sure if it works but can you try replacing `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, container, false);` with `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scout, null, false);`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either, I'll make a post about it tomorrow, thank you very much for your help though

Comment: @SamerAlabi you are welcome my friend. I'll let you know if i find any solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It does nothing because:

- `R.id.data_add` cannot be found in `fragment_scout`

The `replace` method of fragment transaction will replace any view in the container (R.id.data_add), however the `FragmentTransaction` does not manage the container.

Fix:

- Move the replace action to fragment's parent view like this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504274/fragmenttransaction-inside-a-fragment?answertab=oldest#tab-top)